# Angular 7 - Set variable click event with *ngFor property

Tags: angular

I would like to set different methods to be called at the `(click)` event. I created an array of dictionaries in the `ts`-File:

```
headerElements = [
{
  descriptor: "Name",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/name-32.png",
  cursor: "default",
  event: "null"
},
{
  descriptor: "Price",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/description-32.png",
  cursor: "pointer",
  event: "orderByPrice()"
},
{
  descriptor: "Link",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/timer-32.png",
  cursor: "default",
  event: "null"
},
{
  descriptor: "Datum",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/timer-32.png",
  cursor: "pointer",
  event: "null"
}
];
```

The `orderByPrice`-Method looks like this:

```
  orderByPrice() {
    this.isSortedAsc = !this.isSortedAsc;
    const direction = this.isSortedAsc ? "desc" : "asc";
    this.gearPieces = this.gearService.getGearComponentsOrderByPrice(direction);
  }
```

I call it like this in the `html`-File:

```
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let header of headerElements">
        <img src={{header.icon}} width="32" height="32" style="cursor: {{header.cursor}};" (click)="{{header.event}}"/>{{header.descriptor}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, setting a specific method to be called on `(click)` gives me this error:

> Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where
>   expression was expected at column 0 in [{{header.event}}]

Is it even possible, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy solution will be (If `headerElements` variable data is not retrieved from server and is locally defined):

**Change headerElements.event as follows:**

```
headerElements = [
{
  descriptor: "Name",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/name-32.png",
  cursor: "default",
  event: () => {return this.test1();}
},
{
  descriptor: "Price",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/description-32.png",
  cursor: "pointer",
  event: () => {return null;}
},
{
  descriptor: "Link",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/timer-32.png",
  cursor: "default",
  event: () => {return null;}
},
{
  descriptor: "Datum",
  icon: "/assets/imgs/timer-32.png",
  cursor: "pointer",
  event: () => {return this.test2('It works!');}
}
];
```

Also, modify HTML click event as follows:

```
(click)='value.event()'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Instead of function names, you can directly attach the function references to the event prop in your object. So if you have a method:

```
orderByPrice() {
    console.log("order by price called");
}
```

attach the references like:

```
headerElements = [
  {
    descriptor: "Price",
    icon: "/assets/imgs/description-32.png",
    cursor: "pointer",
    event: this.orderByPrice //<---- assign the actual reference of the function
   },
   .
   .
]
```

**Old answer** (*I don't know what was I thinking*)

You can create reference for the methods in your class. Something like:

```
orderByPrice = () => {
    console.log("order by price called");
}
```

Use the function references for assigning to `event` to header elements instead of their names

The create your object like:

```
headerElements = [
  {
    descriptor: "Name",
    icon: "/assets/imgs/name-32.png",
    cursor: "default",
    event: null
  },
  {
    descriptor: "Price",
    icon: "/assets/imgs/description-32.png",
    cursor: "pointer",
    event: this.orderByPrice //<---- assign the actual reference of the function
  },
  {
    descriptor: "Link",
    icon: "/assets/imgs/timer-32.png",
    cursor: "default",
    event: null // <-- as described in comments have it falsy, actual null
  },
  {
    descriptor: "Datum",
    icon: "/assets/imgs/timer-32.png",
    cursor: "pointer",
    event: null
  }
];
```

Have your HTML like:

```
  <th *ngFor="let header of headerElements">
    <img src={{header.icon}} width="32" height="32" style="cursor: {{header.cursor}};" (click)="header.event && header.event()"/>{{header.descriptor}}
  </th>
```

**Edit**

(Based on the comments)

This part contains checks and explanations if it is correct to have a variable in an angular class referencing a function.

I checked the component instance when we add a variable as a function reference rather than adding a named function in the class.

So, When a named function is added it appears in the prototype of the component instance. But if I have a variable reference to the function then the variable(so the function) appears directly in the component instance(this means code duplication).

To avoid this, we can add the function to the prototype of the class.

```
  AppComponent.prototype['orderByPrice'] = (): void => {
    console.log("order by price called");
  }
```

I couldn't find any other differences. I am open to suggestions, counter questions and correcting my mistake if this is not correct.

Thanks!

Comment: `header.event` evaluates to true since it's string

Comment: And btw it's not correct because that's not how Angular methods are defined

Comment: @CristianTraìna: Right! let me rectify thtis.

Comment: I also add that if he/she receives the object from the server, he can map strings to functions explictly, maybe with a switch-case

Comment: And, the last thing, is that you can use the elvy operator `header?.event()`. I had written my own answer but since you were faster I deleted it, so let's integrate :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna: Okay, let me see if it is not suggested to created functions like this in angular.

Comment: @CristianTraìna: Hmm, let me see what can I do if the names come from the server. And haha, you can definitely write your answer if you have something else in mind. **Edit** Perhaps that check for safe navigation shouldn't be on `"header". Header is always present, its the event which is not!

Comment: @CristianTraìna: I don't think I have anything else in mind if the function name comes from the server other using an `event: eval(this.funcName)`. Which I suggest not!

Comment: @CristianTraìna: I have updated my answer, I couldn't find any other reasons why not to have functions other than the way I have described. If this is not true, please guide me to some references where I can find out why not to have function references in a variable.